# Why are my Database Diagrams now blank after upgrading to SSMS 18.12.1

Tags: database, ssms, diagrams

I upgraded **SSMS** this morning to 18.12.1, but when I open my database diagrams all of them are displayed as blank pages.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Might be better asked in https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have encountered a compatibility issue with the new version of SSMS. One solution you could try is to install the latest service packs and updates for SSMS 18.12.1, as these may include fixes for compatibility issues with database diagrams.

To install the latest updates, follow these steps:

Open SSMS 18.12.1 and go to the "Help" menu.
Select "Check for Updates" from the menu.
If any updates are available, follow the on-screen instructions to download and install them.
After installing the latest updates, try opening your database diagrams again to see if the issue has been resolved. If the diagrams are still blank, you may need to use a different tool to create and manage your database diagrams. Some options to consider include:

Using a different version of SSMS that is compatible with your database diagrams.
Using a third-party database design tool such as [Creately.](https://creately.com/diagram-type/database-design/)
Exporting your database diagrams as image files and viewing them using a different tool, such as Microsoft Visio or a web-based diagram editor.
By trying these solutions, you may be able to fix the issue and view your database diagrams correctly in SSMS 18.12.1.